# Setting up programmatically the Youtube YTPlayer for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, youtube, youtube-api

I am having problems setting up the YTPlayer from Youtube API programmatically and not over Storyboard as they show in their [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)..

This is what I have attempted to do but not luck, the video won't event load..

This is my viewDidLoad where I tried to set everything up.. Also, I almost forgot to say that I downloaded their master [framework](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) and added to my project. I changed the path as well for the .html file. I have already tried as they show with Storyboard and works but I really wanna to be able to do it programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myView = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 275)];
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];

    [self.myYoutubePlayer loadWithVideoId:@"Yf5_ZQcP7y0"];

    self.playBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 400, 120, 80)];
    [self.playBtn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.playBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    self.stopBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 400, 120, 80)];
    [self.stopBtn setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.stopBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.stopBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(stopVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [self.view addSubview:self.playBtn];
    [self.view addSubview:self.stopBtn];

}
```

And the play and stop methods...

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
    [self.myYoutubePlayer playVideo];
}

- (IBAction)stopVideo:(id)sender {
    [self.myYoutubePlayer stopVideo];
}
```

If more information is needed please ask first, I will be happy to provide it.. :) thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have problem when run those code on iOS 8.1: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/40. Do you face that? I only warning but i am afraid Apple reject my app.

Comment: I don't get any of those problems.. You can check my youtube player and use it.. Let me know how it goes.. Go [here..](https://github.com/JV17/YoutubePlayer)

Comment: Thank you, but error show only in auto full screen mode or load player without playerVars, i fix it by set player size with screen size!

Comment: I think it was to be with [this...](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/7) Check if you have that in the player framework.. But, what I meant is that I don't get any of those errors using my own framework in fullscreen or inline..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I had here was that the `YTPlayerView` framework didn't had properly define the iframe.html file to be loaded and use for the player. So, I fixed changing the `TYPlayerView.m` within the function `-loadWithPlayerParams:` and change whatever is there for the path of this file..

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YTPlayerView-iframe-player"
                                                 ofType:@"html"
                                            inDirectory:@""];
```

This will make the job done..! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error on your code.

You're calling "loadWithVideoId" on "self.myYoutubePlayer" and it should on "self.myView"